# ArangoDB insert edge doesn't exists

Tags: arangodb

I want to create unique edge between docment collection C1 and C3. 

The unique constraint is **id** and **kid**.

I use the flow aql to create it, but i get more than one edge in the same **id** and **kid**.

how can i achieve it?
sorry for my poor english:)

`for i in C1
filter i.id != null and i.id != ''
  let exist = first(
    for c in C2
    filter i.id == c.id and i.kid == c.kid
    limit 1
    return c
  ) 
filter exist == null
 let result = first(
   for h in C3
   filter i.kid == h.kid
   limit 1
   return h
 )
insert{_from:i._id, _to:result._id, id:i.id, kid:i.kid} INTO C2`

Comment: If the combination id and kid is unique (as you mention in your post), then a simple join between C1 and C3 should get you what you need. If you are getting duplicates, that means that id and kid are not enough by themselves to be unique and you either need to use  different more unique attributes or you need to clean up c1 and c3 first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My English not very good too^)!
But I think, that i see where you made a mistakes.
First, for your two collection, you can use this code:

```
    LET data = [
    {"parent":{"ID":"YOU_MUST_WRITE_HERE_ID_C1"},"child":{"KID":"YOU_MUST_WRITE_HERE_KID_C3"}},
    {"parent":{"ID":"YOU_MUST_WRITE_HERE_NEXT_ID_C1"},"child":{"KID":"YOU_MUST_WRITE_HERE_NEXT_KID_C3"}}
    ]
FOR rel in data
    LET parentId = FIRST(
        FOR c IN C1
            FILTER c.GUID == rel.parent.ID
            LIMIT 1
            RETURN c._id
    )
    LET childId = FIRST(
        FOR c IN C3
            FILTER c.GUID == rel.child.KID
            LIMIT 1
            RETURN c._id
    )
    FILTER parentId != null AND childId != null
    INSERT { _from: childId, _to: parentId } INTO C2
    RETURN NEW
```

I hope that it help you.

Second - Why do you use the С2 collection in this fragment?

```
let exist = first(
    for c in C2
```